# Python + Selenium: как в имя скриншота автоматически добавлять название теста и параметр ids или номер?

Tags: python, selenium, тестирование, скриншот

Изучаю написание тестов на Python + Selenium на основе Page Object.

В общем виде код самого теста выглядит следующим образом:

```
pytest.mark.parametrize("first_name", [double_first_name, empty_form, long_first_name],
                     ids=["double_first_name", "empty_form", "long_first_name"])
def test_reg_form_name(browser, first_name):
    passport_reg_page = RegForm(browser)
    passport_reg_page.go_to_site()
    passport_reg_page.reg_page()
    passport_reg_page.reg_first_name(first_name)
    passport_reg_page.reg_button()
    passport_reg_page = RegFormExpectations(browser)
    passport_reg_page.reg_expect_name()
    assert rt_passport_reg_page.reg_expect_name()
    browser.save_screenshot('screenshots/test_reg_1.png')
```

Как написать и вызвать функцию, чтобы в имя скриншота автоматически добавлялось название теста + параметр ids или хотя бы название теста + номер каждого прогона параметра? Например:

```
browser.save_screenshot(f'screenshots/{"test_reg_form_name"}+"_"+{"ids"}.png')
```

или

```
browser.save_screenshot(f'screenshots/{"test_reg_form_name"}+"_"+{"001,002,003..."}.png')
```

Comment: Что у вас является именем скриншота? Я вижу у вас уже есть попытка использовать форматирование строки, вам что то не понятно F-строкам?

Comment: хотелось бы оформить вызываемой функцией (для большой группы тестов) формирование имени скриншота в следующем формате: (`<папка_для_скриншотов>/<название_скриншота.png>`), где `<название_скриншота> = <название_теста_в_котором_получен_скриншот>+<название_параметра_с_которым_выполнен_тест>` либо `<название_теста_в_котором_получен_скриншот>+<возрастающий_номер_по_порядку>`

Comment: Ну так это и есть то что у меня в ответе, название файла это строка, что бы динамически формировать строку нужно использовать форматирование строк.